# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okio.BufferedSource.rangeEquals(JLokio/ByteString;)Z

Tags: spring, maven, retrofit2, okhttp, okio

I am integrating Outlook API and for making HTTP Calls I am using **Retrofit version 2.3.0 and okHttp3 version 3.9.1.**
However when I'm making an HTTP Call, for example :

```
 // Create a logging interceptor to log request and responses
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
  interceptor.setLevel( HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY );

  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor( interceptor ).build();

  // Create and configure the Retrofit object
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl( authority ).client( client ).addConverterFactory( JacksonConverterFactory.create() ).build();

  // Generate the token service
  TokenService tokenService = retrofit.create( TokenService.class );

  try
  {
     return tokenService.getAccessTokenFromAuthCode( tenantId, getAppId(), getAppPassword(), "authorization_code", authCode, getRedirectUrl() ).execute().body();
  }
  catch ( IOException e )
  {
     TokenResponse error = new TokenResponse();
     error.setError( "IOException" );
     error.setErrorDescription( e.getMessage() );
     return error;
  }
```

I am getting following exception :

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okio.BufferedSource.rangeEquals(JLokio/ByteString;)Z
```

Below is my partial pom.xml :

```
    <!-- JACKSON DEPENDENCY FOR JSON PARSING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- RETROFIT DEPENDENCY FOR SENDING HTTP REQUESTS -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
      <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
      <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can some one help me figure out, what's wrong with this?

Comment: It is very likely that you also have a dependency that uses okio 1.0.0 version. In that case you need to move it below in your pom.xml. Run mvn dependency:tree to double check.

Comment: @Paras I am getting same problem. How you have resolve these problem?

Comment: @Nitish, the problem existed on a dev server, it was working fine with my local, however I could not investigate the issue further. I guess you should delete everything from your local maven repo and build the project again, it may resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedSource
```

is in *okio* project *version 1.13.0*.
Both dependencies `com.squareup.retrofit2` and `com.squareup.okhttp3` use this version. Also in this version this method is included. Version-wise it looks okay.

**Local Environemnt**

Now make sure to clear your maven repository. Maybe an old version got hung up somewhere. After that do a maven update project and a clean install.

**Tomcat Environment**

If this is happening in your tomcat make also sure to delete the `work/Catalina/localhost/` folder, because sometimes things could be cached there.

Comment: I am facing same problem. I am using gradle to build my android project not maven. Do you have any idea to resolve this issue?

Comment: I’d say you remove your local repository and build everything up new. Also check if you only have the 1.13.0 version in your project and no other

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue while executing a MapReduce job via YARN. In my case, an existing downgraded okio version was present which was overriding the external libraries of the application. I changed it to okio 1.13.0 and the issue was fixed.

It was this location for me:

`/home/vagrant/bigdata/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib`

Answer (score 0):

This could be because a conflict with an existing `Okio` version, provided by a dependency.

See [Spark and Influx: OKIO conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481868/spark-and-influx-okio-conflict), there is a conflict with Apache Spark.

Use Maven / Gradle dep. tree export to see all transitive dep, or (in my case) :

```
jar tf /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.3.2.6.3.0-235-hadoop2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar | grep okio
```

This will list:

```
okio/BufferedSource.class
```

Then extract the `okhttp` pom.xml:

```
jar xf /usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.3.2.6.3.0-235-hadoop2.7.3.2.6.3.0-235.jar META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.xml
cat META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp/pom.xml | grep version
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar issue executing Spark job on EMR via YARN, as Okio/Okhttp dependencies for an external library used in the application were being overridden by those distributed on a system class path for Spark.

Resolution: Shade/relocate the Okio dependency in the external library's build.

Comment: Hi! Can you provide an example of how this is done? I can relocate okhttp, but cannot seem to get it to relocate okio

Comment: @Igneous01 
you can find the example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70612283/3365806